# Latitud y Longitud de un Circulo en OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

Buenas!

Quisiera conseguir la Latitud y la Longitud de un circle en OpenLayers.

```
var geometry = evt.feature.getGeometry();
var radius = Math.round(geometry.getRadius() * 100) / 100;
var center = geometry.getCenter();
var lat = ????
var lon = ????
```

Geometry.getCoordinates() me da error "is not a function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe dicho método en [`ol.geom.Circle`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html). Entre los posibles métodos que existen en esta clase que te pueden servir son:
[`getCenter()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html#getCenter), [`getFisrtCoordinate()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html#getFirstCoordinate), [`getLastCoordinate()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html#getLastCoordinate)

```js
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector()
});


var circle = new ol.geom.Circle([-0.3, 38.5], 10);

var circleFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: circle
});

layer.getSource().addFeature(circleFeature);

// Feature
var center = circleFeature
  // Geometry
  .getGeometry()
  // ol.Coordinate ([x, y])
  .getCenter();
var [lon, lat] = center;
console.log(center, lon, lat);
  
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    zoom: 2
  })
});

map.addLayer(layer)
```

```css
#map, html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.2/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.2/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Pero entonces, los valores x e y que devuelve getCenter(), son la latitud y la longitud? Gracias.

Comment: Dependiendo del sistema de referencia que estés usando serán unas coordenadas u otras.

Comment: Veras, estoy utilizando var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(ol.proj.transform([latd, lond], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), 1000); para crear el circulo. Pero los valores que me devuelve getCenter() es diferente a la longitud y la latitud.

Comment: 'EPSG:4326' son coordenadas geográficas (longitud, latitud), 'EPSG:3857' son coordenadas proyectadas (Proyección UTM), por lo tanto coordenadas (x, y). Primero comprueba las coordenadas que obtienes sin transformar, ¿en qué sistema de referencia están (lond, latd)? En ese código que has puesto estás transformando de 'EPSG:4326' a 'EPSG:3857'. Por lo tanto si tus coordenadas están en 'EPSG:4326' ya las tienes en longitud, latitud.

Comment: Un fallo que veo es que montas el array como [latd, lond] y debería ser [lond, latd]. [latitud, longitud] es una convención errónea. Por ejemplo, si te digo que me des las coordenadas cartesianas, me las darás en una lista así [x, y]. Pero, para coordenadas geográficas la gente tiende a decir [latitud, longitud] porque supongo "suena mejor".

Comment: Ok. Perfecto. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.